¿Por qué no me puedo conectar a mi base de datos usando localhost y me veo obligado a conectarme usando explícitamente mi nombre de servidor?
Qué tal a todos. Tengo un problema grave entre manos.
No me puedo conectar a la base de datos de un programa que estoy desarrollando para un cliente.
Resulta que cuando tengo que usar localhost no conecta, pero conecta solo cuando le especifico mi nombre de instancia en el ConnectionString. Si le tengo que entregar el programa al cliente no puedo estar adivinando el nombre de instancia de SQL Server para que funcione en su computadora.
Este es el problema:
_connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=HEAVEN;Trusted_Connection=True;";

Y este es el que tiene mi instancia:
_connectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-PA935D9\\MEPBD;Database=HEAVEN;Trusted_Connection=True;";

Cuando uso localhost. Me tira error 40.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server)'

Ya intenté el tema de los Named Pipes, los habilité y aún así me sigue tirando error.
Ya no sé que hacer y no encuentro la solución apropiada en internet.
¿Alguna duda?

Desconozco porqué no funciona. Has probado añadiendo la IP 127.0.0.1? Aquí te dejo una herramienta útil que quizás te ayuda. https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Vale aclarar que cuando haces un deploy, no siempre la base va a estar en localhost, y por eso se usan archivos de configuracion, donde van estas cosas, y los cuales hay que modificar en el momento de deployar. Esa cadena no deberia ir embebida en tu sistema, si no que la tenes que sacar del archivo de configuracion de tu sistema.

Revisa los privilegios del SQL a ver si tienes todo en orden. compara con otro para que valides bien.

En realidad sí que te puedes conectar usando localhost, pero si SQL Server está ejecutándose en una instancia con nombre debes ponerla:
_connectionString = "Server=localhost\\MEPBD;Database=HEAVEN;Trusted_Connection=True;";

Resulta que puedes tener varias instancias (instalaciones) de SQL Server en una sóla máquina, para diferenciarlas, cada una tiene un nombre de instancia, que hay que especificar para conectarse, si no, ¿cómo sabes a cual de ellas hay que conectarse?
Existe también la posibilidad de instalar una instancia sin nombre, que se llama instancia predeterminada y que sólo puede haber una. En ese caso para conectarse a la instancia predeterminada no se especifica el nombre y la cadena de conexión sería:
_connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=HEAVEN;Trusted_Connection=True;";

En vez de localhost puedes poner (local) o incluso . pero siempre debes poner el nombre de la instancia si ésta no es la predeterminada:
_connectionString = "Server=(local)\\MEPBD;Database=HEAVEN;Trusted_Connection=True;";

_connectionString = "Server=.\\MEPBD;Database=HEAVEN;Trusted_Connection=True;";


En lugar de localhost, puedes utilizar (local) como nombre.
_connectionString = "Server=(local);Database=HEAVEN;Trusted_Connection=True;";

Eso en SQL Server, es equivalente a localhost.
Aunque en realidad, ese valor lo deberías dejar almacenado como configuración (web.config, app.x.config, etc.).
Esto incluso permitiría que tu base de datos y tu aplicación existan en diferentes servidores (aumentando escalabilidad).

Ya lo intenté pero me sigue arrojando error. ¿Alguna alternativa?
